# Not able to concatenate strings when using alter table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Error: Syntax error at or near '('
Line 8

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.testprocedure()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    declare 
        counter integer := 1; 
    begin
        ALTER TABLE schema.test 
        RENAME TO CONCAT('test', counter);
        -- tried SELECT concat as well..
        counter++;

    END;
$procedure$
```

This is my first stored procedure in postgres, and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `RENAME TO` must come an SQL identifier (a name), not a string.

Since you can use parameters only for data values, not for identifiers, and moreover parameters can only be used with `SELECT` and DML statements, you cannot do it like that.

Rather, you'll have to construct an SQL string and execute it with `EXECUTE` (dynamic SQL). Be careful to avoid SQL injection problems - use `format`:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'ALTER TABLE myschema.test RENAME TO %I',
              CONCAT('test', counter)
           );
END;
```

The placeholder `%I` is for identifiers.